# Is there anything I can do to optimize this mysql query?

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery, left-join

I am hoping some of you who are experts in mysql can help me to optimize my mysql search query...

First, some background:

I am working on a small exercise mysql application that has a search feature.

Each exercise in the database can belong to an arbitrary number of nested categories, and each exercise can also have an arbitrary number of searchtags associated with it.

Here is my data structure (simplified for readability)

```
TABLE exercises
  ID
  title

TABLE searchtags
  ID
  title

TABLE exerciseSearchtags
  exerciseID -> exercises.ID
  searchtagID -> searchtags.ID

TABLE categories
  ID
  parentID -> ID
  title

TABLE exerciseCategories
  exerciseID -> exercises.ID
  categoryID -> categories.ID
```

All tables are InnoDB (no full-text searching).

The ID columns for exercises, searchtags and categories have been indexed.

"exerciseSearchtags" and "exerciseCategories" are many to many join tables expressing the relationship between exercises and searchtags, and exercises and categories, respectively. Both the exerciseID & searchtagID columns have been indexed in exerciseSearchtags, and both the exerciseID and categoryID columns have indexed in exerciseCategories.

Here are some examples of what exercise title, category title and searchtag title data might look like.  All three types can have multiple words in the title.

```
Exercises
    (ID - title)
    1 - Concentric Shoulder Internal Rotation in Prone
    2 - Straight Leg Raise Dural Mobility (Sural)
    3 - Push-Ups 

 Categories
    (ID - title)
    1 - Flexion
    2 - Muscles of Mastication
    3 - Lumbar Plexus

 Searchtags
    (ID - title)
    1 - Active Range of Motion
    2 - Overhead Press
    3 - Impingement
```

Now, on to the search query:

The search engine accepts an arbitrary number of user inputted keywords.

I would like to rank search results based on the number of keyword/category title matches, keyword/searchtag title matches, and keyword/exercise title matches.

To accomplish this, I am using the following dynamically generated SQL:

```
  SELECT 
   exercises.ID AS ID,
   exercises.title AS title, 
   (

    // for each keyword, the following 
    // 3 subqueries are generated

    (
     SELECT COUNT(1) 
     FROM categories 
     LEFT JOIN exerciseCategories 
     ON exerciseCategories.categoryID = categories.ID 
     WHERE categories.title RLIKE CONCAT('[[:<:]]',?) 
     AND exerciseCategories.exerciseID = exercises.ID
    ) + 

    (
     SELECT COUNT(1) 
     FROM searchtags 
     LEFT JOIN exerciseSearchtags 
     ON exerciseSearchtags.searchtagID = searchtags.ID 
     WHERE searchtags.title RLIKE CONCAT('[[:<:]]',?) 
     AND exerciseSearchtags.exerciseID = exercises.ID
    ) +

    (
     SELECT COUNT(1) 
     FROM exercises AS exercises2 
     WHERE exercises2.title RLIKE CONCAT('[[:<:]]',?) 
     AND exercises2.ID = exercises.ID
    )

    // end subqueries

    ) AS relevance

    FROM 
    exercises

    LEFT JOIN exerciseCategories
      ON exerciseCategories.exerciseID = exercises.ID 

    LEFT JOIN categories
     ON categories.ID = exerciseCategories.categoryID

    LEFT JOIN exerciseSearchtags
     ON exerciseSearchtags.exerciseID = exercises.ID 

    LEFT JOIN searchtags
     ON searchtags.ID = exerciseSearchtags.searchtagID

    WHERE

    // for each keyword, the following 
    // 3 conditions are generated

    categories.title RLIKE CONCAT('[[:<:]]',?) OR 
    exercises.title RLIKE CONCAT('[[:<:]]',?) OR 
    searchtags.title RLIKE CONCAT('[[:<:]]',?) 

    // end conditions

    GROUP BY 
     exercises.ID

    ORDER BY
     relevance DESC

    LIMIT 
       $start, $results
```

All of this works just fine.  It returns relevant search results based on user input.

However, I am worried that my solution may not scale well.  For example, if a user enters a seven keywords search string, that will result in a query with 21 subqueries in the relevance calculation, which might start to slow things down, if the tables get big.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can optimize the above?  Is there a better way to accomplish what I want?  Am I making any glaring errors in the above?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might me be able to provide a better answer if you also provided some data, particular some example keywords and example `title`s from each of your tables so we can get a sense of what you're trying to actually match on.  But I will try to answer with what you have provided.

First let me put in English what I think your query will do and then I'll break down the reasons why and ways to fix it.

```
Perform a full table scan of all instances of `exercises`
  For each row in `exercises`
    Find all categories attached via exerciseCategories
      For each combination of exercise and category
        Perform a full table scan of all instances of exerciseCategories
          Look up corresponding category
            Perform RLIKE match on title
        Perform a full table scan of all instances of exerciseSearchtags      
          Look up corresponding searchtag
            Perform RLIKE match on title
        Join back to exercises table to re-lookup self
            Perform RLIKE match on title
```

Assuming that you have at least a few sane indexes, this will work out to be `E x C x (C + S + 1)` where `E` is the number of exercises, `C` is the average number of categories for a given exercise, and `S` is the average number of search tags for a given.  If you don't have indexes on at least the IDs you listed, then it will perform far worse.  So part of the question depends particularly on the relative sizes of `C` and `S` which I can currently only guess at.  If `E` is 1000 and `C` and `S` are each about 2-3 then you'll be scanning 8-21000 rows.  If `E` is 1 million and `C` is 2-3 and `S` is 10-15, you'll be scanning 26-57 million rows.  If `E` is 1 million and `C` or `S` is about 1000, then you'll be scanning well over 1 trillion rows.  So no, this won't scale well at all.

1) The LEFT JOINs inside of your subqueries are ignored because the WERE clauses on those same queries forces them to be normal JOINs.  This doesn't affect performance much but it does obfuscate your intent.

2) RLIKE (and its alias REGEXP) do not ever utilize indexes AFAIK so they will not ever scale.  I can only guess without sample data but I would say that if your searches require matching on word boundaries that you are in need of normalizing your data.  Even if your titles seem like natural strings to store, searching through part of them means you're really treating them as a collection of words.  So you should either make use of mysql's full text search [capabilities](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) or else you should break you titles out into separate tables that store one word per row.  The one row per word will obviously increase your storage but would make your queries almost trivial since you appear to only be doing whole word matches (as opposed to similar words, word roots, etc).

3) The final left joins you have are what cause the `E x C` part of my formula, you will being doing the same work `C` times for every exercise.  Now, admittedly, under most query plans the subqueries will be cached for each category and so its not in practice quite as bad as I'm suggesting but that will not be true in every case so I'm giving you the worst case scenario.  Even if you could verify that you have the proper indexes in place and the query optimizer has avoided all those extra table scans, you will still be returning lots of redundant data because your results will look something like this:

```
Exercise 1 info
Exercise 1 info
Exercise 1 info
Exercise 2 info
Exercise 2 info
Exercise 2 info
etc
```

because each exercise row is duplicated for each exercisecategory entry even though you're not returning anything from exercisecategory or categories (and the categories.ID in your first subquery is actually referencing the categories joined in that subquery NOT the one from the outer query).

4) Since most search engines return results using paging, I would guess you only really need the first X results.  Adding a LIMIT X to your query, or better yet LIMIT Y, X where Y is the current page and X is the number of results returned per page will greatly help optimize your query if the search keywords return lots of results.

If you can provide us with a little more information on your data, I can update my answer to reflect that.

*UPDATE*

Based on your responses, here is my suggested query.  Unfortunately, without full text search or indexed words, there are still going to be scaling problems if either your category table or your search tag table is very large.

```
 SELECT exercises.ID AS ID,
        exercises.title AS title,

        IF(exercises.title RLIKE CONCAT('[[:<:]]',?), 1, 0)
        +
        (SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM categories
           JOIN exerciseCategories ON exerciseCategories.categoryID = categories.ID
          WHERE exerciseCategories.exerciseID = exercises.ID
            AND categories.title RLIKE CONCAT('[[:<:]]',?))
        +
        (SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM searchtags
           JOIN exerciseSearchtags ON exerciseSearchtags.searchtagID = searchtags.ID
          WHERE exerciseSearchtags.exerciseID = exercises.ID
            AND searchtags.title RLIKE CONCAT('[[:<:]]',?))

   FROM exercises
```

ORDER BY relevance DESC
     HAVING relevance > 0
      LIMIT $start, $results

I wouldn't normally recommend a HAVING clause but its not gonna be any worse than your RLIKE ... OR RLIKE ..., etc.

This addresses my issues #1, #3, #4 but leaves #2 still remaining.  Given your example data, I would imagine that each table only has at most a few dozen entries.  In that case, the inefficiency of RLIKE might not be painful enough to be worth the optimizations of one word per row but you did ask about scaling.  Only an exact equality (`title = ?`) query or a starts with query (`title LIKE 'foo%'` ) can use indexes which are an absolute necessity if you are going to scale up the rows in any table.  RLIKE and REGEXP don't fit those criteria, no matter the regular expression used (and yours is a 'contains' like query which is the worst case).  (It's important to note that `title LIKE CONCAT(?, '%')` is NOT good enough because mysql sees that it has to calculate something and ignores its index.  You need to add the '%' in your application.)

Comment: thank you for your thoughtful reply.  Please see my updated question.  Regarding: 2) Because these tables are InnoDB, full text searching is not an option.  (And I am a bit reluctant to create a seperate row for each word in a title...) 4) I do indeed have a LIMIT to the query - I just omitted it in the question.  It is in there now.  3) This may not be an easy question to answer... but is there any other way to structure the joins to avoid returning all the redundant data you mention?  Thanks again for your help, it's much appreciated.

Comment: @Travis, I've added to my answer based on your responses.

Comment: thanks again for the very informative answer.  Your point about scaling is well taken.  Ultimately I do not think the exercises table will be larger than 10000 rows, and the categories and searchtags tables will be significantly less than that.  So I think I will see how it performs before I worry about seperating every word into it's own row.  But food for thought, nevertheless.  And your other tips are much appreciated.

Comment: (Also I was not aware that using CONCAT (?,'%') forced a full table scan.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try running explain plan for the query and look at the rows that currently do not use an index. Add indexes strategically for those rows.

Also, if possible, reduce the number of RLIKE calls in the query, as those will be expensive.

Consider caching results to reduce database load using something like memcached in front of the database.